# Python tkinter files

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Напишите программу с интерфейсом, которая будет по нажатию кнопки создавать много файлов внутри папки «**temp**». 
Количество файлов нужно выбирать через `spinbox` на интерфейсе.

Моя попытка, но он создает только один файл, второй час сижу не понимаю как сделать, не могли бы вы подсказать:

```
from tkinter import *


spinbox_widget = None

def create_many_files():
    global spinbox_widget
    if spinbox_widget is not None:
        with open("spinbox_widget", "w") as file:
            a = file.write("")
            a = spinbox_widget.get()

def create_ui():
    root = Tk()

    root.title("Name")
    root.geometry("300x250")

    btn = Button(root, text="Click", bg="green", command=create_many_files)
    btn.pack()

    sbx = Spinbox(root, width=25, bg="blue", fg="white", from_=1, to=500)
    sbx.pack()
    global spinbox_widget
    spinbox_widget = sbx

    print(sbx.get())

    root.mainloop()

create_ui()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
from tkinter import *


spinbox_widget = None

def create_many_files():
    global spinbox_widget

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    
    a = int(spinbox_widget.get())
    while a > 0:
        with open(f"temp/spinbox_widget_{a}.txt", "w") as file:
            file.write(f"Hello, spinbox_widget_{a}")
        a -= 1
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

def create_ui():
    root = Tk()

    root.title("Name")
    root.geometry("300x250")

    btn = Button(root, text="Click", bg="green", command=create_many_files)
    btn.pack()

    sbx = Spinbox(root, width=25, bg="blue", fg="white", from_=1, to=500)
    sbx.pack()
    global spinbox_widget
    spinbox_widget = sbx

    print(sbx.get())

    root.mainloop()

create_ui()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо попробую

Comment: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'temp/spinbox_widget_5.txt'

Comment: получается нужно создать прям папку temp?

Comment: @Youngprogrammer   у вас же в теле вопроса написано, что файлы нужно соэдать внутри папки «temp». У вас есть сложности с созданием папки «temp»?

Comment: нет все оке, спасибо вам большое

Comment: @Youngprogrammer  пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: да уже, совсем забыл